# Can we have $ab=0$ in a ring, where $a,b$ non zero?

Tags: ring-theory

In a ring if I have $ab=0$ can $a$ and $b$ both be non zero? I know if they have inverses it's easy to show one must be zero.

Comment: I think you will find it interesting to look up integral domain on for example wikipedia.

Comment: Consider the ring of integers modulo $6$.

Comment: Obviously yes ...these elements are called zero divisors.in $Z_{6}$ consider the elements 2 and 3

Comment: The ring $\Bbb R\times \Bbb C$, with componentwise sum and product, $a=(1,0),\ b=(0,1)$.

Answer (score 6):

Consider for example the ring $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

In that ring we have $$2\cdot 3=0 \\ 3\cdot 4 =0 \\ \text{ etc } $$

Every multiple of $6$ is $0$ in that ring.

Answer (score 5):

What is the product of 
$$A = \pmatrix{0&-1\cr 0&0}$$

and

$$B = \pmatrix{0&1\cr 0&0}$$
?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$, i.e. multiplication and addition modulo $n$, where $n$ is a composite number.